# How to store and retrieve variable with custom type

Tags: swift, nsobject, codable, nscoding

I have a variable **identity** with type **ETIdentity** that I need to store in ViewController1 and retrieve in ViewController2,

ViewController1

```
//Variables
var activationCodeFromCore, serialNumberFromCore, entityNameFromCore, deviceIdFromCore, registrationCodeFromCore, entityFromCore: String?
    var activationCode, serialNumber, entityName, deviceId, registrationCode, entity: String?
    var counter: Int = 0
var storedIdentity: ETIdentity?
```

Below is the **storedIdentity** that I need to keep

```
let storedIdentity = BridgeSDKUtils.performClassicActivation("26586-05858", withActivationCode: "8998-6857-1357-1870", "entidad0");
        GlobalIdentity.identity = storedIdentity;
```

```
func softTokenDataService() {

        let storedIdentity = BridgeSDKUtils.performClassicActivation("26586-05858", withActivationCode: "8998-6857-1357-1870", "entidad0");
        GlobalIdentity.identity = storedIdentity;

        self.activationCode = "8998-6857-1357-1870"
        self.serialNumber = "26586-05858"
        self.entityName = "entityData\(counter)"
        self.deviceId = "\(String(describing: storedIdentity?.deviceId))"
        self.registrationCode = "\(String(describing: storedIdentity?.registrationCode))"
        self.entity = "\(storedIdentity!)"
    }

...

func getEntityCore()
    {
        //Variables that are going to be stored
        self.activationCodeFromCore = activationCode
        self.serialNumberFromCore = serialNumber
        self.entityNameFromCore = entityName
        self.deviceIdFromCore = deviceId
        self.registrationCodeFromCore = registrationCode
        self.entityFromCore = storedIdentity
    }

...

//SecureStorage Function
func saveEntityToCoreData()-> Bool {

        self.softTokenDataService()

        var SavedItem:Bool = true

        var arr : [[String: Any]] = [[
            "activationCode": self.activationCodeFromCore,
            "serialNumber": self.serialNumberFromCore,
            "entityName": self.entityNameFromCore,
            "deviceId": self.deviceIdFromCore,
            "registrationCode": self.registrationCodeFromCore,
            "entity": self.entityFromCore]]

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arr, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

        if self.saveRutSwitchOn
        {
            SecureData.save(key: "entityData0)", data: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        SavedItem = self.saveRutSwitchOn

        return SavedItem
    }
```

ViewController2

```
struct Person {
    var activationCode: String
    var serialNumber: String
    var entityName: String
    var deviceId: String
    var registrationCode: String
    var entity: String
}

struct EntityModel: Codable {
    let activationCode, serialNumber, entityName, deviceId, registrationCode, entity: String?
}

if let loadedData = SecureData.load(key: "entityData0") {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let entityData = try decoder.decode([EntityModel].self, from: loadedData)
                entityData.forEach { (EntityModel) in

//Here I Imagine something like this
//var identity: ETIdentity?
//identity = EntityModel.entity
////Here I have the identity, so I can manipulate it like needed, because is from type ETIdentity I can access its methods.
//identity?.getOTP(Date())

                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Reference Data:

**GlobalIdentity.swift**

```
struct GlobalIdentity{

    static var identity : ETIdentity?

}
```

**ETIdentity.h**

```
@interface ETIdentity : NSObject<NSCoding> {
@private
-(NSString*)getOTP:(NSDate*)time;
@end
```

**EDIT**
The problem is that the variable **entity** (where I need to call its parameters in ViewController2), is not a String, so it crashes, it doesn't work. I also tried to put the variable identity with the type I needed `var identity: ETIdentity?`, but ETIdentity isn't in protocol with **Codable** (to work with struct so I can call them in ViewController2)

Comment: where problem comes?

Comment: Hello @ShauketSheikh, I updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: then what is the type of entity

Comment: ETIdentity Is the entity Type

Comment: I updated my ans.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and found basic thing that you are missing is your entity seems to be another model like a dictionary or some other type if it is dictionary then do this. Currently your `SecureData.load(key: "entityData0")` contain all the data that return array of entity models, And your Data object `loadedData` must contain `entity` object, Why not you try to implement `Codable` for your `entity` like this.

```
struct SortedArryModel: Codable {
var sorterarrkey: String? // if your array contain strings
}
```

And use this `SortedArryModel` in your `EntityModel`

after that you can get your array like [key:string], just convert that string to array.
**Suggestion:** in your case better to use JsonSerialization instead of codable, if you still want to apply codable then your elements should conform codable protocol. Like I mentioned above, implement your entity as model that confrom codable protocol.